# Gunicorn ImportError: No module name myApp

Tags: python, django, heroku, gunicorn

I am trying to deploy my code on Heroku but gunicorn is giving error `ImportError: No module named inventory`.

My Directory Structure

```
--server
  |
  |--server
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── home
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── admin.py
    │   ├── migrations
    │   │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── models.py
    │   ├── tests.py
    │   ├── views.py
    ├── inventory
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── admin.py
    │   ├── migrations
    │   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
    │   │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── models.py
    │   ├── serializer.py
    │   ├── tests.py
    │   ├── views.py
    ├── manage.py
    └── server
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── settings.py
        ├── urls.py
        ├── wsgi.py
```

wsgi.py

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "server.server.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)
```

Basically my main server Django project is in `/server/server/settings.py`
Need Help here

Answer (score 1):

The DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE parameter should be set from the root of your project, that should be:

> os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE",
>   "server.settings")

Comment: initially it was same as above and was giving error `no module name settings`

Comment: I'm not sure if you need 3 levels of 'server' directories or the __init__.py file in the second one.

All my projects have only 2 levels of the {{project_name}} directories and that init file is not there.

Anyway **I have no experience with Heroku** and maybe is a required feature for Heroku, but sounds strange.

Comment: i have client folder in 1st level server folder. client folder have react.js code

Comment: Why don't you try to remove the __init__.py file in the second level (the one next to manage.py) and set settings as mentioned above?

Comment: same `ImportError: No module named settings`

Comment: And with 2 levels of 'server'?

'server.server.settings'